# Java text and keyword qualification

Tags: java, string, algorithm, text-analysis, keyword-search

I have a 140 characters texts and a set of keywords. 
What I want to do is to write an algorithm that will help me compute a percentage matching between my text and keywords in order to qualify a text as repesenting an IT event annonciation.

For example: 
Text: "Tomorrow will take place our weekly event which about computer. We will discuss about how to implement algorithms. This will be very great."
keyword: "event, computer, database, Software, algorithms"

Here the matching is 3 words over 5 keywords which is 60%

Does that make sense, using word count and compare it to the number of keyword ? Is this approch accurate?
Does anyone has dealt with something like this before?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this makes definitely sense. However, you will have to evaluate in practice whether it is precise enough for your purpose. It depends pretty much on the texts you are dealing with.

If you want to try something that is a bit more advanced but not too complex: [Cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) is another common measure to compare texts.

There are tons of algorithms and libraries for text classification. [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/) is a nice Java library that might help you.

If you are interested in using a library, you find a good overview in the top answer to this [quora question](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-classification-machine-learning-libraries-in-Java).